# Run PS Script with arguments

Tags: c#, powershell, arguments

I'm trying to run powershell script from relative path (script is placed in project folder) with arguments.

This is what i tried:

```
    public static void RunPSScriptWithArgumentsFromScriptsFolder(string NameOfScriptFile, string arguments)
    {
        string RelativePathToApp = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        Process proc = Process.Start("C:\\windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe ", @"-noexit -File """+RelativePathToApp+"\\Scripts\"" +NameOfScriptFile +arguments);
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Problem is when i run it my powershell window just flash once and disseapers even with -noexit switch.

This is script which im trying to run for better reproducing problem:
https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4378-windows-10-decrapifier-18xx-19xx

Any ideas what could be wrong?

PS: My Set-ExecutionPolicy is set to Unrestricted

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing quote on the `-File` parameter. It might help if you save the argument string to a variable and set a breakpoint so you can examine it in the debugger and determine if it's correct.

Comment: I would recommend using the Automation module for running powershell scripts (with arguments). https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: @Jawad Can i run already written script using this? Because rewrite that script into pipelines would be pain.

Comment: @Rufus L Thanks for idea, save it into variable i found string did look different than i supposed i repaired and now it works.